# a = JSON.parse('{"hello":"world"}') gives internal server error

Tags: ruby, json

I am new to Ruby. I am not using any framework like rails or Sinatra. I just tried to write the following code:

```
a = JSON.parse('{"hello":"world"}')
```

When I view that script in a browser, I get an Internal Server error. If I remove this line, the script runs fine and loads the page. I looked in the error logs and don't see any error messages that state specifically what's wrong with this line, instead I get vague premature end of script headers in other ruby files I've included.

Why is `JSON.parse()` giving me problems and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you `require 'json'`?

Comment: when I do a `require 'json'` that also causes an internal server issue on its own. So I went into bash and did a `gem install json_pure` and restarted apache.  But when I reload my ruby script in the web browser, still the same error.

Comment: Why did you restart Apache? Ruby has nothing to do with Apache. If you're trying to run code under Apache, then you need to show us a lot more information, such as how you're interfacing Ruby and Apache, such as by using Passenger or Unicorn. If you need to run Ruby code under a HTTPd, I'd recommend you look into using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) which makes it a lot easier to interface code with a web-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

First I had to do this in bash

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then I had to go into my ruby scripts and change my shebang line from `/usr/bin/ruby` to `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`

Then on scripts where I want to use `JSON.parse()` I have to do a `require 'json'`.